# Azure Application Insights preserves log data when it is moved from one subscription to another?

Tags: azure, migration, azure-application-insights

I have to move resources in Azure from one subscription to another one. One of these resources is Application Insights.

The continuous export feature in Application Insights is not being used, so the logs are only preserved for 3 months.

I spent a while looking for answer, but so far I did not find the right answer. Also, it is not listed in the supported resources (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-support-resources), but I did validate the move operation and it is definitely supported.

I would like to know if the Application Insights will preserve the log data or it will be gone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is listed in the [supported resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-support-resources#microsoftinsights), the resource type of Application Insight is `microsoft.insights/components`.

[image]

And I test it for you, the Application Insight will preserve the log data.

1.Before moving:

[image]

2.After moving to another subscription:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Dit this move also preserve the instrumentation key?